# Apex param or Action Function doesn't work

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I would like to get param in Visualforce page.
But, I can't get.

1.User input text, and click button in Visualforce page.
　User add rows to input text.(I used javascript)
2.In next page, we want to display these text.
So,We have to get these text(name= "title" & "num" ), pass from Visualforce to apex.

What is wrong?

Page1

```
    <apex:page controller="EntryController" sidebar="false"  docType="html-5.0" id="page" tabStyle="Account"  >
    <apex:form >
        <div id="all">
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:pageBlock title="input field">
                    <table id="emtable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>title</th>
                            <th>text</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="text" name="title" size="50" /></th>
                            <th><input type="text" name="num" size="5"/></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div id="div2"></div>
                    <input type="button" value="add row" onclick="clickBtn4()"/>
                    <input type="button" value="get value" onclick="clickBtn5()"/>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:outputPanel>      
        </div>
        <div id="footer_button">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!toSelect}" value="　cancel　" /> 
            <apex:commandButton action="{!toEntry}" value="　entry　" onclick="{jsfunc()}"/>
        </div>
        <apex:actionFunction name="actfunc" action="{!toEntry}" rerender="view">
            <apex:param id="actprm" name="actprm" value="" assignTo="{!ctlpara}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javaScript">

    function clickBtn4(){
        var table = document.getElementById("emtable");
        var rows = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = rows.insertCell(-1);
        var cell2 = rows.insertCell(-1);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="title" size="50" value="">';
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="num" size="5" value="">';
    }
    function clickBtn5(){
        var elements = document.getElementsByName("title");
        //取得した一覧から全てのvalue値を表示する
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            alert(elements[i].value);
        }
    }
    function jsfunc(){
        var elements = document.getElementsByName("title");
        alert(elements[0].value);
        actfunc(elements[0].value);
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Page2

```
<apex:form >
    <div id="all">
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!ctlpara}"></apex:outputText>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
</apex:form>
```

EntryController

```
public without sharing class EntryController {
public string ctlpara{get;set;}
// コンストラクタ
public EntryController(){ 
    this.ctlpara = '';
}



/*to Page1*/
public PageReference toSelect(){
    pageRef = Page.Page1.setRedirect(false);
    return pageRef; 
}

/*to Page2*/
public PageReference toEntry(){
    this.ctlpara = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('actprm');

    System.debug('[s]'+ctlpara);
    pageRef = Page.Page2.setRedirect(false);
    return pageRef; 
}
```

}